# Can someone explain what this complex css does

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-float

```
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ .col-md-auto {
    width: 33.3333%;
}
```

I came across this css on source code of a website and trying my hard to guess what it actually does.I am a newbie so finding it complex to deal with this complex css.I look at the w3 schools to figure out what those symbols means i could get the meaning of symbols but still could not figure out what the whole expression is doing.Any suggestions will be great help.

Comment: If there are exactly 3 elements with a `class="col-md-auto"` which are siblings, style them each with 1/3 width of the parent container.

Comment: @4castle can you please explain in detail how that css actually works?

Comment: Is there a specific part of the syntax you don't understand? Each part should be searchable on Google.

Comment: @4castle i googled it but the expression does not make any sense from my understanding. according to me first select the div with class "col-md-auto" which is the first child of its parent and then select the 3rd last div with same class.why are we using it twice ?

Comment: The only time the first element can also be the third-from-last element is when there are exactly 3 elements. That's the main trick.

Comment: @4castle why this line .col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3) is being used twice?

Comment: The first line styles the first element, the second line styles the siblings of the first element (i.e. the second and third elements).

Comment: @4castle what does this line .col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3) actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there are exactly 3 elements with a class="col-md-auto" which are
>   siblings, style them each with 1/3 width of the parent container.

Following on [**4castle**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5743988/4castle) explanation:

[`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

> The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
>   or zero value for n. More simply stated, the selector matches a number
>   of child elements whose numeric position in the series of siblings
>   matches the pattern an+b.

[`nth-last-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)

> The :nth-last-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings after it in the document tree, for a given positive or
>   zero value for n.

[General sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

---

```
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3)~.col-md-auto {
  width: 33.3333%;
}
```

`.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3)` selects the first element, while `.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3)~.col-md-auto` selects the elements following the first child, but **not** the first-child itself, that's why the first selector is required.

```css
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.col-md-auto:first-child:nth-last-child(3)~.col-md-auto {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.row {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.row::after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
}

.col-md-auto {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  height: 5em;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-md-auto:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-auto"></div>
  <div class="col-md-auto"></div>
  <div class="col-md-auto"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-auto"></div>
  <div class="col-md-auto"></div>
  <div class="col-md-auto"></div>
  <div class="col-md-auto"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with [nth test tool](http://nth-test.com/).
Also there are two awesome sites for beginners

[Css Reference](http://cssreference.io/)

[Html Reference](http://htmlreference.io/)